# Is it possible to connect two headphones to the phone without any splitter?

Tags: headphones, bluetooth-audio, headphone-jack

I need to connect two headsets to my smartphone. I know that I can't do it via Bluetooth, but maybe its possible to connect one via Bluetooth and another via audio jack?

Comment: [Check What Hardware is Being Used](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-output.html#CheckHardware) implies both (Bluetooth and audio ) cannot be *simultaneously* used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even via Bluetooth. Just search for proprietary Bluetooth technology ShareMe. For example:
http://www.cnet.com/news/get-two-pair-of-shareme-bluetooth-headphones-for-56-98/
[http://www.amazon.com/ShareMe-Bluetooth-Headphones-Wireless-Technology/dp/B0152GBS66](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0152GBS66)

ShareMe technology lets you to stream music wirelessly to another ShareMe equipped headphones.